# DataView RowFilter is not giving proper results

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, dataview, rowfilter

I am using Data Grid View to show 1000 Rows and 800 Columns of Data (only one character per cell). There is a Check Box column also. I have added a context menu item like "View Selected Cells". On click of that one  I am trying to show only Checked Rows. For that one earlier I was setting `Visible` property of unchecked rows to `False` by looping through each. This is taking so much time.

So I tried using `DataView` Control by applying `RowFilter`. It looks some what faster but. But some of the checked rows are not visible.

e.g. If I have 10 Rows, out of them 5 rows are checked. Then only 4 rows are visible. Actually it should show 5 rows which are checked.

I tried these things

1. `dView.RowFilter="CheckBoxCol";`
2. `dView.RowFilter="CheckBoxCol=true";`

with both of these things I am getting same problem. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Is there an underlying bound data source for your dataviewcontrol (such as a data table, list of objects) or are you populating the data grid manually?

Comment: Both the options you show should work well - I've provided an answer based on the only reason I can think for this to happen. If my guess is wrong please provide detailed information on exactly how to reproduce this issue. Code behind of a minimal solution would be best.

Answer (score 0):

Both the methods you have shown will work as a `RowFilter` on a boolean column.

It is most likely that you are hitting an issue with the way the `DataGridView` handles edits - they are not committed to the underlying data source until the current editing cell loses focus, and with the most common way of showing the context menu on the grid, the cell does not lose focus.

That is, if you show your context menu doing something like this:

```
void dataGridView1_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {            
        contextMenuStrip1.Show(dataGridView1, e.Location);
    }
}
```

Then the most recent check box you changed will not have flushed its change to the data view.

The solution to this is in two parts. First you need to introduce a binding source which sits between the data view and the datagrid.

```
bindingSource1.DataSource = dView;
dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
```

Then you need to add the following code to a 'CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged' handler on the data grid view:

```
void dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.IsCurrentCellDirty)
    {
        dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
    }
}
```

Finally, within the code where you apply the filter you also need to call `EndEdit` on the binding source:

```
private void filterToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bs.EndEdit();
    dvSections.RowFilter = "CheckBoxCol";
}
```

---

In my previous experience the binding source was not necessary, but I haven't tried with quite this mix of context menu and data view, when I tried I found that the `bs.EndEdit()` was needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think David Hall is correct (sorry I do not have enough points to comment only - which is what I intend to do here)

Try Table.AcceptChanges on the underlying source table of the Data Grid View if possible.

This should commit any lingering changes to the Table and subsequently to the DGV